# Xamarin Android (Visual Studio 2015) Could not connect to the debugger

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with the android debugger (Visual Studio 2015) as it always stops immediately after starting debug (it works just fine without debugging), I had my machine reset and reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 but it does not help.

**Here is the log from logcat**: monodroid-debug Error accepting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:8896) Address already in use

**Here is the log from Xamarin log**:

```
Mono.Debugging.Soft.ConnectionException: Could not connect to the debugger. ---> Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException: Exception of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' was thrown.

Server stack trace: 
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive(CommandSet command_set, Int32 command, PacketWriter packet)
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.VM_GetVersion()
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Connect()
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.connect()
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.Connect(Connection transport, StreamReader standardOutput, StreamReader standardError)
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.ConnectInternal(Socket dbg_sock, Socket con_sock, IPEndPoint dbg_ep, IPEndPoint con_ep)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.ConnectCallback.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.<>c__DisplayClass9.b__8(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I had same issue and I was able to connect debugger by following this:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.cz/2016/02/fix-for-could-not-connect-to-debugger.html

In short:

- Disable "Use fast deployment (debug mode only)" in Android project -> Properties -> Android options -> Packaging
- Enable "Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version" in Hyper-V manager go to VM -> Settings -> Processor -> Compatibility

Comment: Only the first "Use fast deployment (debug mode only" did the trick for me!

Comment: On mac using Visual Studio for Mac i only had to uncheck/disable "Fast Assembly Deployment" for my Android project (Options -> Android Build -> General -> Packaging and Deployment). Thanks!

Comment: I only needed to "Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version" for my VM - very nice!

Comment: This both combination changes alone perfectly works for me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Actually turning fast deployment ON solved it for me lol

Answer (score 2):

For me, this turns out to be an issue of DELL laptop running on Windows 10, after I rolled back to Windows 8.1, it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

> Error accepting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:8896) Address already in use

This has been reported to Xamarin as [Bug 34476](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34476).

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is for VS 2015. Recently with visual studio 2017 version 15.2 has this issue.
 Uninstalling the visual studio and downgrading to  previous working VS helped in my case. Hope soon they will fix the bug. 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95555/how-to-downgrade-visual-studio-2017-version-15-2-to-15-0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on VS 2019.

What fixed it for me was deleting my emulator and re-adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same issue in VS 2022, suddenly it was saying 'could not connect to debugger' when I tried to run the xamarin-android solution.

I checked answer from @akl22 and also checked with this article https://localjoost.github.io/fix-for-could-not-connect-to-debugger/
So Before going to perform the steps mentioned in the answer above by @akl22, I did the following

```
I restarted the visual studio, 2022
Cleaned the solution
Rebuilt the solution
Ran the solution again.
```

Finally it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If akl22's answer did not work, go to android options -> advanced, check the supported architectures. Sometimes x86 and x86_64 are required for emulators. I faced this same problem, and enabling these helped me.